# Change page TITLE tag to match page's H1 tag in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I dynamically change the page's title tag based on my page's H1 tag in AngularJS.

I know in jQuery I could do something like:

```
var title = $('#content').find('h1').first().text();
if (title.length >= 1)
{
    document.title = 'My Site Name  |  ' + (title);
}
else {
    document.title = 'My Site Name';
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish the same thing in AngularJS?

**I would rather not put it in the app.js because to me it seems wrong to be putting content -- which may change -- mixed with the code.   If I edit the text of the H1 in my partial view it needs to automatically change the title.**

Comment: Have you tried binding them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to bind the title to static h1 content, you can use the following directive:

```
var app = angular.module('bindTitle', []);
app.directive('bindTitle', ['$document', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, iElement) {
      $document[0].title += ' | ' + iElement.text();
    }
  };
}]);
```

The usage will be:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Site Name</title>
<head>
<body>
  <h1 bind-title>Your title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And `Your title` will be appended to the page title on page load. i.e. `My Site Name | Your title`

Edit: auto append title on h1 element

```
var app = angular.module('bindTitle', []);
app.directive('h1', ['$document', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, iElement) {
      $document[0].title += ' | ' + iElement.text();
    }
  };
}]);
```

And content inside `<h1>` elements will be appended to the page title.

Comment: This worked.   The only minor caveat I found was that if a page didn't have an H1 decorated with _bind-title_ or _data-bind-title_ the title would not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

It is there in the documentation,

Try something like this

```
  angular.module('documentExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {
      $scope.title = $document[0].title;
      $scope.windowTitle = angular.element(window.document)[0].title;
    }]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rlq032m5KTVLSRMDRHvr?p=preview

Comment: This is getting the title, I need to set the title based on the H1 on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's data binding on the `<title>` element with either [`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) or [`ng-bind-template`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate).

Of course, you need to have the desired value in a variable on your module/controller (e.g., `$scope`) to use data binding. If the value isn't part of the scope, Angular can't offer any "better" solution than jQuery or standard JavaScript (you'll need to find the `<h1>` tag on the page and extract the text in some fashion regardless).

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'My Page';
});
```

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<head>
<!-- Direct binding example -->
<title ng-bind="title"></title>

<!-- Or, template example -->
<title ng-bind-template="My Site{{ title.length > 0 ? ' | ' + title : ''}}"></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$watch` to change the title

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="demo">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <input type="text" ng-model="title" />
    </div>
</body>
<script>
angular.module('app', []).controller('demo', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch($scope.title, function() {
    document.title  = $scope.title;
  });
}]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to set same `model` for your title and for your `h1`

Take this [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/j2o659tm/) as an example. When you are writing something in that textbox, `name` is modified in 2 places, in the same time.

Note: You should do this in a `MasterController` for your `Layout` html page.